# Session Storage in Redis

Tags: spring-boot, session, websocket, redis, synchronization

I have developed a chat application using Java and the Spring framework. The WEBSOCKET_MAP is a ConcurrentHashMap used to store Server objects for all users. It helps track all connected users to the server and indexes them based on their user ID.

The @OnOpen method, is triggered when a WebSocket connection is established between the client and the server. It receives the client's Session and the path parameter id (user ID), and stores the current user's Server object in the WEBSOCKET_MAP.

The @OnMessage method, By receiverId we can get the corresponding server and session, so then can have a sending process.

The issue is I plan to deploy the web application on multiple cloud servers, which may result in incomplete data in the HashMap of different servers. I want to use Redis and its publish-subscribe functionality for session storage and Synchronization, but I encountered difficulties in storing the Session class in Redis. Is there any good method? Now I only thought of serializing the session and storing it in Redis. Here is the code.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat/{id}") // Each connected client will have its own server instance

@Component
public class Server { 

public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Server> WEBSOCKET_MAP = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); // Stores all users

public Session session; // Current session

public String userId; // Current user

@OnOpen
public void OnOpen(Session session, @PathParam("id") String id) throws Exception {
    this.userId = id;
    this.session = session;
    Server server = WEBSOCKET_MAP.get(id);
    if (server == null) {
        WEBSOCKET_MAP.put(id, this);
    } else {
        WEBSOCKET_MAP.put(id, this);
    }
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String tmp) {
    Message cur = JSON.parseObject(tmp, Message.class);
    Integer fromUserId = cur.getFromId();
    Integer toUserId = cur.getToId();
    // ...
    if (WEBSOCKET_MAP.get(String.valueOf(toUserId)) != null) {
        Future<Void> tmpf = sendText(String.valueOf(toUserId), cur);
        while (!tmpf.isDone()) ;
    }
    Future<Void> tmpr = sendText(String.valueOf(fromUserId), cur);
    while (!tmpr.isDone()) ;
    System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```